# Do TADs derive from operons?

Tags: genetics, molecular-evolution, operons, tad

TADs (Topologically associated domains) are DNA sequences in the eukaryotes genome (except plants) that are between two sequences named "Insulator". The genes in TAD just are affected by enhancers and suppressors that are in the same TAD.
This structure can be seen in operons that exist in bacteria. Is there evidence to say that TADs derived from operons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "no".

[Operons](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/15642184/#:%7E:text=It%20was%20thought%20that%20polycistronic,to%20more%20than%20ten%20genes.&text=Like%20bacterial%20operons%2C%20eukaryotic%20operons,expression%20of%20functionally%20related%20proteins.) have very closely coupled regulation, even in eukaryotes. The classic operons are polycistronic, meaning that transcription of adjoining genes occurs as part of the same process.

TADs on the other hand are merely ([not always very well defined](https://academic.oup.com/nar/article/45/6/2994/3059658)) regions in between insulators, as you say. They probably have some common regulatory context, but it is nothing like the direct coupling observed in operons.